# Read file from packages

Tags: java, filereader

This is my current code:

```
public void copy(String file, String region) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    File inputFile = new File(curDir+"\\RADS\\system\\"+file+"-"+region+".cfg");
    File outputFile = new File(curDir+"\\RADS\\system\\"+file+".cfg");

    FileReader in = new FileReader(inputFile);
    FileWriter out = new FileWriter(outputFile);
    int c;

    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(c);
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

In this case a file is read from somewhere on the harddrive and is copied. But what i want is that the inputFile is a file from a resourcepackage and i still want to use the same mechanism.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: you want to read a file from a package, like for example `org.mypackage.files`?

Comment: I think he may want to read them from a jar. http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0077.html

Comment: Yes, in this case i want to read in this case /resource/launcher-eu.cfg and after that the contents must be placed in for example C:\program files\game\launcher.cfg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ClassLoader's getResourceAsStream for that purpose:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/RADS/system/" + file + " - " + region + ".cfg");
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamreader(input);
```

The rest of the class should be able to stay the same this way.

For (some) more info: [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Good luck :)

Comment: isint filereader something different then inputstreamreader then?

Comment: @Toby FileReader reads a File directly; but since getResourceAsStream gives you back just an InputStream, you will need to use an InputStreamReader. In the end, the result is the same with one pro: the InputStreamReader might also be reading the InputStream pointing to a file inside your assembled .jar file (which a FileReader will not be able to directly).